# How do I tell Dagit (the Dagster GUI) to run on an existing Dask cluster?

Tags: pipeline, dagster

I'm using dagster 0.11.3 (the latest as of this writing)

I've created a Dagster pipeline (saved as pipeline.py) that looks like this:

```
@solid
def return_a(context):
    return 12.34


@pipeline(
    mode_defs=[
        ModeDefinition(
            executor_defs=[dask_executor]  # Note: dask only!
        )
    ]
)
def the_pipeline():
    return_a()
```

I have the DAGSTER_HOME environment variable set to a directory that contains a file named dagster.yaml, which is an empty file.  This should be ok because the defaults are reasonable based on these docs: https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/dagster-instance.

I have an existing Dask cluster running at "scheduler:8786".  Based on these docs: https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/custom-infra/dask, I created a run config named config.yaml that looks like this:

```
execution:
  dask:
    config:
      cluster:
        existing:
          address: "scheduler:8786"
```

I have SUCCESSFULLY used this run config with Dagster like so:

```
$ dagster pipeline execute -f pipeline.py -c config.yaml
```

(I checked the Dask logs and made sure that it did indeed run on my Dask cluster)

**My question is:**  How can I get Dagit to use this Dask cluster?
The only thing I have found that seems related is this:
https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/execution#executors

...but it doesn't even mention Dask as an option (it has dagster.in_process_executor  and dagster.multiprocess_executor, which don't seem at all related to dask).

Probably I need to configure dagster-dask, which is documented here: https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/libraries/dagster-dask#dask-dagster-dask

***...but where do I put that run config when using Dagit?  There's no way to feed config.yaml to Dagit, for example.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some options:

- you can manually plug in the values that are in `config.yaml` in to the `dagit` playground
- you can bind the config directly to the executor if you do not need to change it ever https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/configuration/configured#configured-api
- you can create a `preset` from that config yaml https://docs.dagster.io/tutorial/advanced-tutorial/pipelines#pipeline-config-presets

Given the context, I would recommend the `configured` API